# Положить данные в класс в классе

Tags: python, классы

Есть класс, в котором есть класс(работаю с disnake, поэтому нельзя вытащить класс снаружи). Я не могу обозначить значения в классе. Как решить проблему?

```py
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
    class subMain():
        def __init__(self1):
            self1.a = self.a #Здесь выходит ошибка
```

Ошибка:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined. Did you mean: 'self1'?
```

Конечно, если написать `class subMain(self)` то тоже выходит ошибка, но ошибка `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: Какая ошибка выходит? Добавьте полный текст ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Думаю, уже не к чему придераться)

Comment: Можно в __init__ добавить аргумент self2 и вместо self писать self2, а при вызове функции указывать экземпляр класс

Comment: class subMain(self)? Вы точно понимаете, какой синтаксис в питоне. Во-первых, self это в первую очередь параметр и он существует только в области видимости функции, во-вторых в скобках вы указывается классы родители. Вам нужно сделать следующее: В инициализации добавить, второй параметр, который будет являться экземляром класса main и далее уже делать с ним, всё что хотите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы вам потребуется изменить структуру класса таким образом, чтобы вложенный класс subMain имел доступ к значениям извне.

Одним из возможных решений является передача ссылки на экземпляр внешнего класса main внутрь вложенного класса subMain. Это можно сделать, добавив аргумент parent к конструктору класса subMain и передавая в него ссылку на экземпляр класса main.

Вот пример исправленного кода:

```
class main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
        self.sub = self.subMain(self)  # Передача ссылки на родительский класс
    
    class subMain():
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.a = parent.a  # Доступ к значению "a" родительского класса
    
    def print_a(self):
        print(f"a = {self.a}")
        print(f"sub.a = {self.sub.a}")


m = main()
m.print_a()
```

Теперь класс subMain имеет доступ к значению a из родительского класса main.